# Positive version of the word crowd

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

The word crowd (as a noun, not a verb), can be fairly negative; it implies, if not disorderliness, then at least people being packed together. Sometimes that’s positive (like if a stadium or a concert draws a crowd), but in the context I’m writing for, it is not.

So what’s a positive version of the word crowd? Something that implies lots of people, but not in a negative way. I’ve looked at many synonyms in various thesauruses, but most are either negative, or have strange connotations — throng, congregation, mob, horde. As you can see, none of them really fit.

Here’s a sample sentence for the way I would like to use the word:

> A crowd gathered, to enjoy the sunshine and company.

Comment: You should include a sample sentence demonstrating how you would use the selected word.

Comment: @KillingTime that’s an excellent idea, thank you! I’ve included it.

Comment: *A gathering,* perhaps?

Comment: The context you give does imply positivity and friendliness. Why does it need qualifying? If a negative situation, the sentence could continue, for example, with "but it became oppressive."

Comment: A 'joyous assembly' perhaps overstates it.

Comment: I suggest "crowd" is only ever negative in context, which "A crowd gathered, to enjoy the sunshine and company" would always negate.

Comment: @WeatherVane perhaps it’s a little too late to change this, considering that it might invalidate some of the answers, but my intention was to use a word that doesn’t imply closeness between the people in the [crowd].

Comment: "When all at once I saw a crowd / A host of golden daffodils". Nothing negative about Wordsworth's use of the word.

Answer (score 2):

I personally find nothing negative (or positive) about the noun *crowd*. (Although the verb *crowd* could be different.) I suspect you are putting too much emphasis on its synonyms. Most (if not actually all) synonyms are related to a word, but they aren't actually identical.

However, an alternative which I can't force (so to speak) into a negative connotation in the same way is [**group**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/group):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   **2 a**: a number of individuals assembled together or having some unifying relationship
>   // a study *group*

So:

> A *group* gathered to enjoy the sunshine and company.

If you need to be explicit about the size of the group (as *crowd* normally implies), you need to also use an adjective:

> A *large group* gathered to enjoy the sunshine and company.

Answer (score 0):

I think crowd is quite neutral, but how about changing the verb to make how they came together more positive?
A crowd assembled
A crowd came together
A crowd united